# How to define the vertical location of navigation text?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am using [`beamer2thesis`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer2thesis/beamer2thesis.pdf), i.e., the `beamerthemeTorinoTh` style to compile my presentation slides.  It is nice but I realized that I need to do some modifications.  The upper header stripes seems quite unnecessary unless I put navigation bar there, to show the sections we are in. I modified the outertheme style file,

```
 \leavevmode%
 \hbox{%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\headerheight,dp=0pt,center]{page header}%
 \usebeamerfont{navigation} \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt   plus1filll}{}%
 \end{beamercolorbox}%
 }%
```

The navigation text locates in the bottom of the colorbox. I expect it is at the center of the box instead of a location so low. Any modification I need to do? By the way, I want the color to be white, not this interaction color, because it looks quite not clear.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted. Now you must be able to upload it. Pl. try. Also it is advisable to provide a complete MWE along with your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `\vbox` and `\vfil` inside the `beamercolorbox` to center its contents:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\headerheight,dp=0pt]{page header}%
  \vbox to\headerheight{\vfil\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

To get the sections colored in white, the beamer templates `section in head/foot` and `section in head/foot shaded` have to be changed:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\color{fg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
```

#### Full example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{TorinoTh}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\headerheight,dp=0pt]{page header}%
    \vbox to\headerheight{\vfil\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}\vfil}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@torinoth@line]{second header}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\color{fg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\frame{}
\section{Conclusion}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: example headline, centered and with white text color]

**EDIT:** If you want to show only the current section in the headline, you can use the following `beamercolorbox` instead of the above one:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\headerheight,dp=0pt,right]{page header}%
  \vbox to\headerheight{\vfil{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}\secname\hspace*{.3cm}}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks, diabonas.  One more thing, is that possible to show only the current section, i.e., the other sections are invisible instead of shaded. Using \insertsection does not work.

Comment: @seasoul I've updated my answer to support this. Simply use the alternative `beamercolorbox` I provided, the rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: Thank you, diabonas. I managed to get it work. What I have to mention is that there is a compile error "undefined control sequence". After searching, I found the solution is add a line in the preamble "\def \secname{}". Until now the problem is solved.

Comment: @seasoul Sounds as if you were using an older version of `beamer` (before `v3.11`, released in September 2011). Anyway, your solution `\def\secname{}` is fine, this is exactly what the newer versions of `beamer` do, too.