# How can I vertically align a beamercolorbox?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I am trying to customize a `beamer` theme. In the footline, information such as author, title, date ... are in several `beamercolorbox`es.

```
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.70\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,left,leftskip=2ex]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{} - \insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.10\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,right,rightskip=2ex]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
```

I can easily manage the height and width of the box but the text is still completely at the bottom of the box. I would like this text to be vertically aligned.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the depth of the boxes to a proper value using `dp=<length>`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.70\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=3ex,left,leftskip=2ex]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{} - \insertshortauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=3ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.10\paperwidth,ht=4.25ex,dp=3ex,right,rightskip=2ex]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that you have a spurious blank space at the end of the second `beamercolorbox`; I removed that space in my example code.

Comment: Thank you it works. However, I do not understand this depth parameter. Is it a sort of z coordinate into the beamercolorbox?
I thought that this depth was related to the layer of the page in order to manage stacking of several beamercolorbox.
Are beamercolorbox really useful here ? Why beamer theme do not simply use parbox or other more simple box ?

Comment: @Ger The depth of a box is the distance betwee the baseline and the botoom of the box; think of the two characters "bg" the box for "b" has a depth of 0pt (there's no downwards strokes), but the depth of the box for "g" is positive (the length of the downwards strokes of the "g" below the baseline).

Comment: @Ger `beamercolorboxes` are, in fact, built using simpler boxes but incorporating ready to use functionality (you can easily control the color, the width, depth, height, the margins, etc.). You could dispense with the use of `beamercolorboxes` and use only `\parbox`es or even `\vbox`es and `\hbox`es, but then your code would be too lengthy.

Comment: Can you add a comment about the "proper value" of dp ? What is the relation between ht and dp ?

Answer (score 14):

The content of a `beamercolorbox` is typeset into a box. With the `ht=<height>` parameter, the height of this box is set to `<height>`, but the content stays at the bottom. You can use the `sep=<dimension>` parameter instead, which adds extra to every side of the box, thus centering the content. If you need to set a fixed height, however (which is quite reasonable for a footline), you can use an additional `\vbox` and `\vfil` inside the `beamercolorbox`, as [described in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49617/3323):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.70\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,left,leftskip=2ex]{title in head/foot}%
    \vbox to7.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{} - \insertshortauthor}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \vbox to7.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.10\paperwidth,ht=7.25ex,right,rightskip=2ex]{date in head/foot}%
    \vbox to7.25ex{\vfil\hbox{\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber}\vfil}%
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting footline]